# Benzyl (3,4-difluorophenyl)carbamate reaction with epoxide in basic conditions

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

I attempted this mechanism, however I am uncertain if I am correct.

[image: reaction]

Comment: The product you've drawn on the bottom line has one more carbon than the product you've drawn on the top line.  Carefully count the number of carbons in the various reaction intermediates.

Comment: What is the uncertainty? Is there a particular step that seems unreasonable to you?

Comment: Thank you I see were I went wrong with that, I'll edit it accordingly. Bar that slip would you say I'm on the right track with the mechanism? @ron

Comment: I'm just asking for confirmation about my method, organic chemistry isn't my strong suit and I was just looking for a second opinion. @jerepierre

Comment: Your mechanism looks correct to me.  Thanks for taking the time to draw clear structures.